Godot 4.2.2: Area3D cant collide with CSGBoxes or StaticBodies
I am currently trying my hand at a 3D ARPG in Godot 4.2.1 (and 4.2.2) and have a problem with collision detection. The collision between my projectile (Area3D with CollisionShape3D) collides with an enemy (CharacterBody3D) as expected, but not with instances of StaticBody3D or CSGBox3D.
Setup:

Collision Layer and Mask on Projectile and all Targets set to 1
body entered and area entered signals on the projectile are connected to respective functions in the script projectiles script
Monitoring is enabled

I am wondering if the problem is that the projectile is an Area3D? Or am I missing something obvious?
Thanks in advance.
What i tried:

changing collision layers and masks
changing the speed of the projectile to a stupendously low value
changing the root node of the projectile to a RigidBody3D (resulted in no collision at all, not even with the enemy


It seems to be this: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/74300

Thanks for your comment, but it was connected to using jolt, not godot itself. I simply forgot that i configured to use jolt....

Jolt is also mentioned in the linked issue, apparently they have a setting for this: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/74300#issuecomment-1999324859

Yeah, I just found that out as well. Concerning the issue described above, it seems to be intended. Thanks!

I found out what the problem is: I was using jolt. When switching back to the default physic engine, everything works like a charm.
Jolt seems to be broken in other areas at the moment (at least for 4.2.1 and 4.2.2), or I just dont handle it right. Another big issue is, that the game just crashes without any hint, when there are runtime error in my scripts. Since I only just started with GDScript, that happened a few times and left me baffled...

If you also found yourself here and are using Jolt3d. The answer is in the advanced project settings of Jolt3D. You will need to enable "Areas detect static bodies". This is not enabled by default.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
